# Vagrant failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, vagrant, virtual-machine, config

I'm tyring to attache ip of a created vm but got th error

My code to attache IP :

```yaml
  config.vm.box = "generic/debian10"
  config.vm.define 'Poll' do |poll|
    poll.vm.hostname = 'Poll'
    poll.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

What error i got :

```
toni@toni-HP-EliteBook-x360-1030-G7-Notebook-PC:~/Work/octopus/B-DOP-400-PAR-4-1-octopus-toni.da-rodda$ sudo vagrant up
Bringing machine 'Poll' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'postgreSQL' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'Worker' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'Redis' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'Result' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> Poll: Checking if box 'generic/debian10' version '3.6.12' is up to date...
==> Poll: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Can someone help me please ?